# Brakes sticking on one side

Tags: brakes, nissan, brake-rotor, altima

I have an 08 Altima. After brakes started sticking and rubbing I replaced pads and in appx a week they were rubbing again, as well as sticking on passenger side. This time I replaced the pads again,as well as replaced the rotor on passenger side. After a couple weeks, same problem. This time I replaced pads(rotor was ok) and calipers on both sides. This was ok for month, maybe... And again same problem!!  Please help, any ideas on the subject.. I have never had this problem before, so I am a bit perplexed!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What did you do as far as maintenance on the slides/guide pins for the calipers?

Comment: Checking those now, as jwh20 suggested, and now you make same suggestion, which actually makes me think that this could indeed be the solution!! Thank you for taking the time to give me your thoughts on the situation. I will post an update ASAP!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the slider mechanism sticking as described in jwh20's answer (This would be noticeable as more wear an one of the brake pads than the other).

I would also check the condition of the flexible brake hoses.  It is possible that there is some kind of kink in the flexible hose that allows brake fluid to be pushed toward the caliper when the brakes are pressed, but resists the fluid's escape when the brakes are released.

Additional useful information by @MTA from the comments -

"The kink can be internal, inside the flexible hose and not visible from the outside. With the car on jack stands, if you step on the brake and release it and then find that you can't rotate the wheel that has unusual wear, loosen the bleeder. If brake fluid spurts out under pressure and the wheel becomes easy to rotate, it's a bad brake hose."

Comment: Just to clarify for the OP, the kink can be internal, inside the flexible hose and not visible from the outside. With the car on jack stands, if you step on the brake and release it and then find that you can't rotate the wheel that has unusual wear, loosen the bleeder. If brake fluid spurts out under pressure and the wheel becomes easy to rotate, it's a bad brake hose.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your slide pins in the caliper bracket are not working as expected.  You mention that you replaced the pads and calipers (which is an odd thing to do) and did it twice.  So you've already spent a lot of money on this thing.

It's always important to service the slide pins when replacing pads and rotors.  If the pins don't slide the calipers will be fixed in place and you will get excessive and uneven wear.

Comment: And I haven't thought about slide pins, that actually sounds promising. I will definitely do that now!

Comment: Only replaced calipers the 1 time, I only replaced pads multiple times, totally apologize for my confusing question ⁉️⁉️

Comment: @Goodoboy78 - If you would please edit your original question with the updated information, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see, I will certainly do that now.

Comment: If calipers are changed and slide pins were lubed find it really hard to accept they are bad again. Perhaps it is the brake line itself pinched or restricting backflow

Comment: @Chris There is no mention of the slide pins being serviced.